# norm inequality, if $x^t e = 0$ with $e=(1,1,...,1)$

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to prove that if $x$  and $y$ are in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\langle x,e\rangle=0 $ where $e=(1,1,...,1)$ then

$$|\langle x,y\rangle |\le||x||_1\frac{y_{\max}-y_{\min}}{2}\qquad \text{for all} \quad y$$

I think that is necessary to use norms inequalities and Cauchy–Schwarz  inequality or Hölder's inequality.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: @Camilo Espitia After a week I got back to this question and posted an answer. Please see if this is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Proof is by induction. Suppose this holds for $n<N$. Since a rearrangement of 
$x_{k}^{\prime }s$ does not change the inequality we may suppose there
exists $m$ such that $\ x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{m}$ are positive and $%
x_{m+1},x_{m+1},...x_n$  are negative. (zero terms can be dropped). Now
let $u_{k}=x_{k},v_{k}=y_{k}$ for $1\leq k\leq m$ and $u_{m+1}=-\sum
_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}$. Let $v_{m+1}=\frac{\sum%
_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}y_{k}}{\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}}$. We apply
induction hypothesis to the vectors $(u_{1},u_{2},...,u_{m+1})$ and $%
(v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{m+1})$.  Assume that at least two of the $x_{k}^{\prime
}s$ are negative so that $m+1<n$. We can conclude, by induction hypothesis,
that $$\left\vert \sum_{k=1}^{m+1}u_{k}v_{k}\right\vert \leq
(\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\left\vert u_{k}\right\vert )\frac{v_{\max
}-v_{\min }}{2}$$. Note that $$v_{m+1}-v_{j}=\frac{\sum%
_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}(y_{k}-v_{j})}{\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}}=\frac{%
\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}(y_{k}-j_{j})}{\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}}=%
\frac{\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\left\vert x_{k}\right\vert (y_{k}-y_{j})}{%
\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\left\vert x_{k}\right\vert }$$ $\leq y_{\max }-y_{\min }
$. It follows from this that $v_{\max }-v_{\min }\leq y_{\max }-y_{\min }$
so we have $$\left\vert \sum_{k=1}^{m+1}u_{k}v_{k}\right\vert \leq
(\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\left\vert u_{k}\right\vert )\frac{y_{\max
}-y_{\min }}{2}$$. Also note that $$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\left\vert
u_{k}\right\vert
=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}x_{k}-\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}=\sum%
_{k=1}^{n}\left\vert x_{k}\right\vert $$ and $$\sum%
_{k=1}^{m+1}u_{k}v_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{m}u_{k}v_{k}-\sum%
_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}\frac{\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}y_{k}}{%
\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}y_{k}$$. This
finishes the proof in this case. If $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-1}$ are positive
and $x_{n}$ is negative then $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}y_{k}=\sum
_{k=1}^{n-1}x_{k}y_{k}-(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_{k})y_{n}=\sum
_{k=1}^{n-1}x_{k}(y_{k}-y_{n})$$ so $$\left\vert
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}y_{k}\right\vert \leq
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left\vert x_{k}\right\vert (y_{\max }-y_{\min })$$
and $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left\vert x_{k}\right\vert =\frac{1}{2}%
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\vert x_{k}\right\vert $$. Hence the desired inequality holds in this case also. The inequality is obvious for $n=1$ so we have finished the proof.

Comment: In this case, $\Vert x\Vert_1\geq 2|x_1|$.

Comment: @W.mu I have edited the answer providing explicit values for $x_2,...,x_n$.

Comment: The definition of the norm $\Vert \Vert_1$ is $\Vert x\Vert_1=|x_1|+|x_2|$, not the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @W.mu  Where is the norm defined? I don't see it in the title or the question. If no norm on an Euclidean space is specified it is always taken as the usual norm.  Normally the norm used is the one that comes from the inner product and since the inner product here is the usual one, the norm has to be the usual one. Unless the question is modified my answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: This is a standard notation $\Vert \Vert_p$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions

Comment: @W.mu After that mad mistake of not reading the right side properly I have come with a proof. Please take a look.